# Is there an app extract the contents of winmail.dat files?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

I use Mac for my work. I received a lot of `winmail.dat` files from senders who are using Microsoft Outlook, but I don’t know how to extract and save it, and the contents are very important for me. I need them to do my work.

This question has been bothering me for a long time, and I am eager to solve it. Does anyone know what method fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[This also supports MAC.](http://www.winmail-dat.com)

Download it and do anything you want with the winmail.dat files.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the build in Mail application and received **a lot** of winmail.dat, may I recommend my product [Letter Opener for macOS Mail](https://www.winmail.help/letter-opener-for-macos-mail).

It opens and displays the files directly inside Apple’s Mail application, so that they appear just like any other email.